# Move buttons below each other in popup using ionicPopup.show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've created this popup using

```
        $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Choose Location...',
        buttons:[
            {
                text: "Current Location",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                    $scope.myLocation();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Previous Locations",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                    $state.go('menu.listSelect');
                    //go to choose location page
                }

            },
            {
                text: "Address Book",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){

                    //go to address book
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(){
                    console.log('cleek');
                    $scope.fillOptionPopup.close();
                }
            },
        ]

    });
};
```

This places the buttons created next to each other like so

[image: buttons next to each other]

Is there a way to make the buttons so they stretch across the width of the popup and each button is on a new line using that format of creating buttons for the popups?

I've used this code in place of the buttons array and it gives me this, which is what I want. But the `ng-click` isn't calling the functions that I made out of the ontap's from the array.

[image]

```
template:   '<button class="button button-positive" ng-mousedown="goMyLocation()">Current Location</button><br>'+
'<button class="button button-positive" ng-mousedown="goMenuList()">Previous Locations</button><br>'+
'<button class="button button-positive" ng-mousedown="goAddressBook()">Address Book</button><br>'+
'<button class="button button-positive" ng-mousedown="closePopup()">Close</button>'
```

Is there a way to get the buttons to be one per row and a full width of the popup?

Comment: did you try using class="button button-full"

Comment: i have yes, it still comes up the say way. also editing the css with width:100%. i think its because the popup reads the array of buttons with a ng-repeat and puts them into one row and one column per button. but i cant find anywhere that i can confirm this with or change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that I read the entire question I can help you. The first code snippet will never do what you want without modifying the popup CSS because of the default popup layout

In order for the second layout to work (using the template) you need to pass the scope parameter to your popup, so the buttons are linked to the scope holding the functions

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicPopup/

Answer (score 15):

There actually another option that I find "cleaner".
In the object passed to the show method you can also define a css class for the popup, so you can use it to override the default ionic styles.

Specifically for your use case:

```
.popup-vertical-buttons button
{
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.popup-vertical-buttons .popup-buttons
{
    display: block;
}
```

and in the object use pass to the show method add:

```
cssClass: "popup-vertical-buttons"
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone interested, this is how I did it...

Before the buttons property, add cssClass: 'popup-vertical-buttons' so that it looks something like this:

```
$ionicPopup.show({
 tite: 'Some Title',
 cssClass: 'popup-vertical-buttons',
 buttons: [
  ...
]
});
```

Then in your CSS add these two lines:

```
.popup-vertical-buttons .popup-buttons {
  display: block;
}
.popup-vertical-buttons .popup-buttons .button{
  display:block;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```